# Linear Algebra - Find the point Q where L and T intersect.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Let *L* be the line passing through the point *P* = (1, −2, −1) with direction vector *→d* = <5, 1, 3>, and let *T* be the plane defined by *x* + *4y* − *2z* = −28. Find the point *Q* where *L* and *T* intersect.

I'm not sure how to solve this problem. Would I find an arbitrary point on the plane first? e.g. (-28, 0, 0)

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Kindly use MathJax for math formatting. You may find tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: This is a pretty simple question! Although I am giving the answer, next time please remember that you should at least give your thinking about the solution and not just the question.

Comment: Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Where did this problem come from? Is it an exercise for a course you’re taking? If so, then there should be at least one example of how to solve such problems in the material you’re meant to have studied already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any point on your line will be of the form $\left( 1 + 5 \lambda, -2 + \lambda, -1 + 3 \lambda \right)$. Now, this also satisfies the equation of the plane (and hence is in the intersection. So we have

$$1 + 5 \lambda + 4 \left( -2 + \lambda \right) -2 \left( -1 + 3 \lambda \right) = -28$$

On solving, we get $\lambda = - \dfrac{23}{3}$ and hence the point of intersection will be $\left( - \dfrac{112}{3}, - \dfrac{29}{3}, -24 \right)$.